# C# byte addition overflow?

Tags: c#, byte

I noticed that when Byte plus Byte, it will produce int, 
Is it possible to let byte a +byte b and produce 255 if it overflows?

```
Byte a=200;
Byte b=200
Byte output = (a+b); // now output equals 144, I want 255
```

Comment: Are you sure that that is a good idea? What's the requirement behind it? Just look: now `output - a` doesn't equal `b` anymore!

Comment: @BernhardHiller there are a lot of use cases where you want that behaviour ... e.g. calculations with colors ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this (untested)?

```
byte output = (byte)(Math.Min(a + b, Byte.MaxValue));
```

Comment: Probably `byte.MaxValue` is a bit more readable than magic constant `255`

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when a number overflows which is not in a [**`checked` statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx).

If you want it to produce 255 then the most simple option I can think of would be to use a ternary operation:

```
byte output = (int)a + (int)b > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : a + b;
```

The other option I can think of would be to create your own data type that handles this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since `a + b` is of type `int` you can easily check:

```
  Byte a = 200;
  Byte b = 200

  byte result = a + b > byte.MaxValue ? byte.MaxValue : (byte) (a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will throw OverflowException:

```
checked
{
    Byte a=200;
    Byte b=200
    Byte output = (a+b);
}
```

And this way you can catch and process it:

```
Byte output;
try
{
    checked
    {
        Byte a=200;
        Byte b=200
        output = (a+b);
    }
}
catch(OverflowException e)
{
    output = Byte.MaxValue;
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

But I suggest you to control your flow yourself. Catching exceptions is bad approach, but if you have complex calculation, it can be troublesome. Just use Math instead:

```
var output = (Byte)Math.Min((int)a+b, Byte.MaxValue);
```